# jQuery- How to determine properties of internal anchor link's parent

Tags: jquery

I am trying to see if an anchor link location is located in a list whose class is "tab":

```
<ul class="etabs">
<li class="tab"><a href="#tab1" alt="">Tab 1</a></li>
<li class="tab"><a href="#tab2" alt="">Tab 2</a></li>
<li class="tab"><a href="#tab3" alt="">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, let's say I visit this page directly:

```
http://www.example.com/page.html#tab2
```

I have:

```
if (document.location.href.indexOf('#') > -1) {

    if ($(window.location.hash).parent('li').hasClass('tab')) { // something wrong here
      alert('its a tab');
    } else {
      alert('not tab');
    }

}
```

I keep getting "not tab". What's wrong with my code?

Comment: is it possible to put a `class` to all the anchor links?

Comment: @silk_route11 Yes, I can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you visit http://www.example.com/page.html#tab2 , then window.location.hash will be #tab2 , which means $(window.location.hash) will be looking for an element with an **id** of tab2.

So add id's to your a tags :

```
<a id="tab2" href="#tab2"
```

Answer (score 0):

try  this to select the a tag with attribute href and #tab2 value;

```
if($('a[href="#tab2"]').parent('li').hasClass('tab')){


}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `jquery` then add a class to all the anchor links(for example :"link").Then the following code will work for you

```
          $("a.link").each(function(){
                if($(this).parent("li").hasClass("tab")){
                    alert("is a tab")
                }else{
                    alert("not a tab");
                }
            })
```